# Get top 5 post count sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

```
$coins = @mysql_query("SELECT coin_id FROM coins WHERE user_id = '".user_id."'")or die (error_sql(mysql_error(),__LINE__,__FILE__));
```

I use this to show how many coins member have, and only the member can see his stats.
I want to show top 5 to public, I did not know how to do that.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this:

```
$coins = @mysql_query("SELECT coin_id FROM coins WHERE user_id = '".user_id."' LIMIT 5")or die (error_sql(mysql_error(),LINE,FILE));
```

Regards.

Comment: but what about the user_id ?

Comment: then something like this if you want the overall top 5: $coins = @mysql_query("SELECT coin_id FROM coins LIMIT 5")or die (error_sql(mysql_error(),LINE,FILE));